# (Node js) How to send notification to specific user?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, sockets, socket.io

i have code for server
server.js

```
var socket  = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var nik = {};

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on( 'new_count_message', function( data ) {
        io.sockets.emit( 'new_count_message', {
            new_count_message: data.new_count_message
        });
    });

    socket.on( 'update_count_message', function( data ) {
        io.sockets.emit( 'update_count_message', {
            update_count_message: data.update_count_message
        });
    });

});
```

and this is how i use that

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "(some_url)",
            data: $("id_form").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend:function(){
                alert('bla..bla..');
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.status) {
                    var socket = io.connect('http://' + window.location.hostname + ':3000');
                    socket.emit('new_count_message', {
                        new_count_message: result.new_count_message
                    });
                } else if (result.status == false) {
                    alert(error);
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, Status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

that function is working perfectly, but it send to all. how to send notif to specific user? i have the ID user that i want to send the notif

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

- With `io.sockets.emit` you emit a message to all sockets. Instead use `io.sockets.in("roomname").emit("message")`.
- As well if you have the socket ID where you want to send the message you can use `io.sockets.connected["socketid"].emit("message")`.
- If you are inside the `io.on('connection')` function and you want to send a message to the same socket you can simply use `socket.emit`.

Another way is:

- When a new socket connects, add this socket to a specific room `socket.join("UniqueUserId")` or `socket.join("UniqueUserSessionId")` ... Then use the 1st option `io.sockets.in("UniqueUserId").emit("message")` or `io.sockets.in("UniqueUserSessionId").emit("message")`

Examples:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    //get the unique socket socketId on connection
    var socketId = socket.id;
    //you can add this socket id to a Database to use it later, etc...

    //use sessionStore like Redis or memStore to get a unique sessionId

    //as well you can extract a cookie with the UserId (you need to secure this to be sure that the user not modified the cookie) (you can use 2 cookies 1 for the userid other for the encrypted password and check if the cookies data is the same than in your users Database) etc etc etc. User Session is a lot better). Read about nodejs session store and socket session. Something like...
    var cookies = qs.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie, "; ");
    var user_id = cookies.user_id; //or some other cookie name;
    socket.join(user_id);

    socket.on( 'new_count_message', function( data ) {

        //all sockets
        io.sockets.emit( 'new_count_message', {
            new_count_message: data.new_count_message
        });

        //same Socket
        socket.emit( 'new_count_message', {
            new_count_message: data.new_count_message
        });

        //specific Socket by SocketId
        //io.sockets.connected["socketid"].emit( 'new_count_message', {
        io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit( 'new_count_message', {
            new_count_message: data.new_count_message
        });

        //all sockets in a specific Room
        //io.sockets.in("roomname").emit( 'new_count_message', {
        io.sockets.in(user_id).emit( 'new_count_message', {
            new_count_message: data.new_count_message
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: thanks for reply,
where i must place this?
io.sockets.connected["socketid"].emit("message").

basically, this not for room/chat, i wanna send a notif to specific user(by select, so that just always 1) :)

Comment: @ChandraPutraWijaya Added examples.

Comment: thanks, a little bit know.
but, when i try use socket.join(), that showing an error. socket.join is not a function

Comment: @nada  I am a little bit new to socket-io. Is the socket ID for every user unique and immutable?

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi i don't know if it's immutable (maybe you can reassign it to a new value) but socketId 'per se' should be unique